# What is the max max and min min for angular form input for integers?

Tags: angularjs

With angular input numbers, I notice that if I enter large numbers they can get rounded to something different.

For example, in this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/k5G7eL8gIzWbSPGocdlQ?p=preview I set a large max number like this:

```
<input type="number" name="input" ng-model="value" min="0" max="9223372036854769" required>
```

Then, if I enter 9223372036854769 in the input field it gets rounded down one.  If I enter 9223372036854767 it gets rounded up one.

Considering only integer numbers (no decimals), what is the maximum integer value inputs can receive without rounding?  And what is the minimum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not related to angular but more so to JavaScript in which numbers have precision up to 2^53 both positive and negative.

[ECMA number spec](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5/)

Comment: Thanks. I now see this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t.  Before I posted the question, I looked up the max javascript number which was clearly larger than this.  But I didn't know about precision limits and I assumed it must be an angular or a html input issue.

Comment: Interestingly, the spec you pointed me to has an error.  In the first sentence on page 30 they meant the number (2^31)−1. But the document formatter raised the "-1" as a superscription so it looks like 2^(31-1).

Answer (score 5):

The value 9223372036854769 is more than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. A good explanation on your problem can be found in http://www.2ality.com/2013/10/safe-integers.html