# ng-reflect-model show incorrect value but the input is right

Tags: angular

The input value is `01020304050607080900010203040506`, and input shows the correct value，However, when I check the ng-reflect-model, the value is `010203040506070809000102030405`. Is there any length restriction for ngModel?

[image]

Comment: Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918607/what-is-the-max-max-and-min-min-for-angular-form-input-for-integers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the max max and min min for angular form input for integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918607/what-is-the-max-max-and-min-min-for-angular-form-input-for-integers)

Answer (score 0):

[ng-reflect-model] has a maximum limit of 30 characters after that your content is truncated. Here in this case `01020304050607080900010203040506` you have 32 character but it is truncated to `010203040506070809000102030405` which has 30 character. You can try with entering more test cases, it will truncate them all and return 30 character result.

Here is a link that may be more useful to understand : [refer](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28786)