# Dropdown selected value not setting in edit mode Angular 10

Tags: angular, angular10

In the edit mode of the form, the value from the database is not selected. I get the correct value in 'service.formData.SalesRepId', but somehow it is not selected. Am I missing something?

[image]

below is the code

```
    <select 
      #select name="SalesRepId" 
      #SalesRepId="ngModel" 
      [(ngModel)]="service.formData.SalesRepId" 
      class="form-control">
          <option value="">-Select-</option>
          <option 
             *ngFor="let rep of this.service.staffUsers" 
             [value]="rep.UserId">
                {{rep.FullName}}
          </option>
    </select>
```

Below is the type-script which retrieves the data. On the console log, I get all the correct SalesRepId

```
this.bsModalRef = this.bsModalService.show(EditSurveyRequestComponent, { class: 'modal-xl' });
    (<EditSurveyRequestComponent>this.bsModalRef.content).isUserRoleAdminFromParent = this.nav.isUserRoleAdmin;
    this.service.getSurveyRequestDetailsById(SurveyRequestId).subscribe(data => {
      this.service.formData = data as SurveyRequests;
      console.log(this.service.formData.SalesRepId);
    })
```

Comment: Can you add the typescript code for adding such value to the control select?

Comment: Added the TS code

Comment: I might be mistaken but shouldn't it be [ngValue]?

Comment: I got the root cause of the issue, but have no idea yet how to resolve this. In my case [(ngModel)] text exceeds 30 characters and is truncated. This way now the option value does not match and the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59315845/ng-reflect-model-show-incorrect-value-but-the-input-is-right?rq=1

Comment: Sample output on F12:  
<select ng-reflect-model="cdb61d00-7fd5-4721-b794-c630aa"> 
 <option  value="44db03bf-b305-4815-9efb-69b1a117413d" ng-reflect-value="44db03bf-b305-4815-9efb-69b1a1"> Erik M </option>
 <option  value="cdb61d00-7fd5-4721-b794-c630aa053030" ng-reflect-value="cdb61d00-7fd5-4721-b794-c630aa"> Alex T </option>
</select>

Comment: Even limiting the characters count to 30 did not help. This is possibly due to the dropdown is inside a modal dialog. The modals open from the edit button against each row in a datatable. So, I feel this is related to some modal scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to store the value in a variable say rapidValue and then use the [{ngModel}] in the html .

```
rapidValue: string;

this.bsModalRef = this.bsModalService.show(EditSurveyRequestComponent, { class: 'modal-xl' });
    (<EditSurveyRequestComponent>this.bsModalRef.content).isUserRoleAdminFromParent = this.nav.isUserRoleAdmin;
    this.service.getSurveyRequestDetailsById(SurveyRequestId).subscribe(data => {
      this.service.formData = data as SurveyRequests;
      rapidValue = this.service.formData.SalesRepId;
    })
```

in the html use -

```
<select 
  #select name="SalesRepId" 
  #SalesRepId="ngModel" 
  [(ngModel)]="rapidValue" 
  class="form-control">
      <option value="">-Select-</option>
      <option 
         *ngFor="let rep of this.service.staffUsers" 
         [value]="rep.UserId">
            {{rep.FullName}}
      </option>
</select>
```